# Can i use System.Web.Helpers.Crypto class in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-framework-version

I am building a .net core web api project but i want to use the system.webhelpers.crypto class. However i am recieving this error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning NU1701  Package 'System.Web.Helpers.Crypto 3.2.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Should i be worried about this or is there a specific namespace that is suitable with .net core?

Comment: This package is not designed for .NET Core. Investigate the types in the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace to find something that achieves whatever it is you're using it for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography?view=net-6.0

Comment: In short: **no**, you can't. But I'm sure it's nothing you can't rebuild in a few lines: so, what functionality are you actually after?

Comment: im wanting to use the haspassword and verifypassword function in the crypto class

Comment: I'm afraid not.You can try to  write [custom method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to hash password.